# class function to add number to array

Tags: javascript

I just want each time the button is clicked for the value to be added to the array. However, when I `console.log(this.arr)` I just get the last value that I entered instead of the previous values

```
class Deposit {
    constructor(){
        this.arr=[];
        this.sum=0;
    }

    addDeposit(value){
        let v=value;
        this.arr.push(v);
        console.log(this.arr);         
    }
}

deposit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let value = input.value;
    let newDeposit=new Deposit();
    newDeposit.addDeposit(value)
});
```

Comment: Your event handler creates a brand new `Deposit()` object (with a brand new empty `arr` array) on every "click" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const deposit = document.getElementById('deposit');

class Deposit {
  constructor() {
    this.arr = [];
    this.sum = 0;
  }

  addDeposit(value) {
    let v = value;
    this.arr.push(v);
    console.log(this.arr)
  }
}

let newDeposit = new Deposit();

deposit.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let value = input.value;
  newDeposit.addDeposit(value)
})
```

```html
<input id="input">
<button id="deposit">Deposit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new instance of `Deposit()` on every click.

To prevent this, bring your `new Deposit()` instantiation outside of the client event, so `Deposit()` only gets instantiated once:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const deposit = document.getElementById('deposit');

class Deposit {
  constructor() {
    this.arr = [];
    this.sum = 0;
  }

  addDeposit(value) {
    let v = value;
    this.arr.push(v);
    console.log(this.arr)
  }
}

let newDeposit = new Deposit();

deposit.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let value = input.value;
  newDeposit.addDeposit(value)
})
```

```html
<input id="input">
<button id="deposit">Deposit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question you have to write newDeposit=new Deposit(); out the arrow function otherwise you overwritten your object...

an example:

```html
   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      class Deposit {
          constructor(){
          this.arr=[];
          this.sum=0;
          }

          addDeposit(value){
              let v=value;
              this.arr.push(v);
              console.log(this.arr)
            }
      }
      let newDeposit=new Deposit();
      var btn=document.getElementById("myBtn");
      btn.addEventListener("click", () => {

          //let value = input.value;
          let value=document.getElementById("myInput").value;
          //let newDeposit=new Deposit();
          newDeposit.addDeposit(value)

      });
    });
    </script>
    <body>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="deposit" value="">
    <button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this helps